# sql purchase items

Tags: sql

I need a stored procedure for solve this problem. I have table with name Items With Values

```
id      qty
1   5
2   10
3   15
```

If a parameter value = 10, and the table will be

```
id      qty
1   0
2   5
3   15
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask - After clarfying this also show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dbms supports window functions (ms sql server 2012+ is used below):

```
declare @prm int = 10;
select id, qty
     , case 
         when qty + tot <= @prm then 0
         when tot > @prm then qty
         else (qty + tot) - @prm 
      end currQty
from (
    select id, qty, coalesce (sum(qty) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) tot
    from
     -- your table here
       (values
         (1,5 )
        ,(2,10)
        ,(3,15)
       ) tbl (id,qty)
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to use a cumulative sum for this purpose.  The rest is just arithmetic.  I like to phrase this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_qty <= @parameter
             then 0
             when running_qty - qty <= @parameter
             then running_qty - @parameter
             else qty
        end) as new_qty
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (order by id) as running_qty
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5ee03eda6770199333843641ed51ba4) is a db<>fiddle.